# MDB2 pear windows installation

Tags: installation, pear, mdb2

I am looking for a guide for installing and using MDB2 pear on my system. i use iss7 and windows vista.... I read the manual but I didn't understand too much...

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [PEAR package installation manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php).